# Ruby/Github: Appropriate general solution for OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError?

Tags: ruby, ssl, github

Every now and then I'm encountering problems with scripts hosted on Github which have been linked using `https`. I've usually managed to get around it one way or the other, but I'm wondering what's the proper way of solving this?

**Here's an example:** I'd like to make use of [this Rails Application template](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/blob/master/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber-template.rb).

Running

```
rails new APP_NAME -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/master/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber-template.rb -T
```

will throw:

```
certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

What is the proper way of going about this situation without editing the script itself?

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried so far as well

```
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```

but I keep on getting the same error.

I also exported the certificate from Firefox as github.com.pem and simply dragged it into my unlocked Keychain Access. The certificate is now listed but the error remains the same.

---

**UPDATE 2**

As awful this solution is, this hack works: http://blog.dominicsayers.com/2011/08/16/howto-use-a-rails-template-from-github-on-windows/

Comment: Did you try to install the root certificates? You can find them on the curl site: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Nope — I only tried to install the github certificate with my clumsy FF export. There's 164 certificates in this file. Would I have to install them all? After splitting the file I suppose?

Comment: I don't really know, this was just a shot in the dark, not really worthy of an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that simply "updating" the certificates is the best option:

```
$ cd /usr/share/curl/
$ sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
$ sudo mv curl-ca-bundle.crt old.curl-ca-bundle.crt
$ sudo mv cacert.pem curl-ca-bundle.crt
```